# NSDate for the beginning of the current day prints as late afternoon on the previous day

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, date, nsdate

I was trying to get the date alone (without time) from today's date using this code:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *date1Components = [cal components: NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"Today without time :%@",[cal dateFromComponents:date1Components]);
```

The result is:

> 2014-10-14 23:01:13.398 TestViewHier[5349:60b] Today without time :2014-10-13 18:30:00 +0000

I am from India, now the time is: 2014-10-14 11:16 pm, but the result shows one day off and some random hour also.

My expected result is `2014-10-14 00:00:00`, because I need to compare this date with another date. I will get a product's expiration date from a service, and if the date is less than or equal to the current date, I need to display the products in an "Expired Products" section. I can compare the two dates by using `NSDate`'s comparison method.

Comment: We can tell you're from India because it's the only major timezone which sits on a half-hour boundary relative to UTC.

Comment: [Please don't bother adding "Thanks" and the like to your posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). You can thank answerers by upvoting if their answers are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

NSDate is always a point in time in UTC (universal time).

You took *your* current time.

You extract year, month and day using your Indian calendar, so you get the values that you expect.

You convert these components to an NSDate. This gives a point in time at the beginning of *your* day in India. Because you are 5 1/2 hours away from UTC, that point in time in UTC would be the previous day at 18:30. In other words, if you had called me on the phone at the start of the day (midnight), and I looked at my calendar and my watch, my calendar would show the previous day, and my watch would show 18:30.

And that is what NSLog displays. The NSDate is absolutely correct; it *is* the start of the day according to your calendar. Your day started at 18:30 UTC.

Comment: OK, but the question is asking how to get his current date (for his time zone), without the time

Comment: @JoelFan: As gnasher has said, OP has what he wants already; a date does not include time zone information. It's _displayed_ in GMT when it's printed out, but the moment in time that it represents _is_ the start of the day 2014-10-14 in OP's time zone.

Comment: @gnasher729: I have executed the above code at 11:16 pm(not the start of the day, its almost end of the day), which means 5:30 pm UTC on the same day. How come it is showing one day off

Comment: @JoelFan: What does it mean by OP time zone?

Comment: @JoshCaswell, a date (even without the time) certainly is affected by the time zone.  OP wants the date to be correct for his time zone, just not include the time

Comment: No, the _display_ of the date is affected by the time zone, @JoelFan, but the date 2014-10-14T00:00:00-5:30 is the **same date** as 2014-10-13T18:30:00+0:00.

Comment: @JoelFan, observe: https://gist.github.com/woolsweater/acfdac54b7b1f23856bb

Answer (score 0):

To get a string with the date without the time use `NSDateFormatter` method: `startOfDayForDate` available in OSX 10.9 and iOS 8.0.

Example:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"date:           %@", date);

NSDate *dateOnlyString = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] startOfDayForDate:date];
NSLog(@"dateOnlyString: %@", dateOnlyString);
```

Output:

```
date:           2014-10-14 18:11:43 +0000  
dateOnlyString: 2014-10-14 04:00:00 +0000
```

But the real problem may be that `NSLog` uses the `NSDate` `description` method. That displays the date/time based on several criteria you may not want. If you want to see the date in a specific format use a `NSDateFormatter` to create the display string.